# All child elements changing, only want the div child whose parent is clicked to change.

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent-child

Trying to get the child of a parent `<div>` to change. There are 5 panels total on the page, and when I click on one of the parents, ALL of the children of all of the panels change.

In addition to the code below, I've uploaded it here: http://intp.co/dev

**The Jquery:**

```
    <script>
        $("div.click").click(function() {
        $("div.click > img").toggleClass("rotated");
        }); 
    </script>
```

**The HTML**

```
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="expander2 click">
            <img src="images/chev.png">
        </div>
        <h1>The Best Header Sample Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="segment2">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
    </div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.click img
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top:34px;
    margin-right:22px;
}

img.rotated 
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `$("div.click > img")` is agnostic of the context - it just selects all elements that apply to this selector in the document, no matter where you execute it.

To select the appropriate elements, you can use the traversal functions, starting off with a certain element and then traversing through the DOM. Remember that `this` is the clicked `div.click` element, so:

```
$(this).children("img").toggleClass("rotated");
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I  might have to use 'this', but  I've not really got a good grasp on it yet!

Answer (score 0):

The failure is, that you're selecting all elements again inside the click function, just refer to `$(this)`

```
<script>
  $("div.click").click(function() {
    $(this).children("img").toggleClass("rotated");
  }); 
</script>
```